# How to render a page in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

I used below code to render a page in the controller action.

```
public function userinforeceiveAction()
{   
    $renderer = new PhpRenderer();

    $map = new Resolver\TemplateMapResolver(array(
    'userinfo' => __DIR__ . '/userinfo.phtml',
        ));

        $resolver = new Resolver\TemplateMapResolver($map);
        $renderer->setResolver($resolver);
        $model = new ViewModel();
        $model->setTemplate('userinfo');

        return new ViewModel();    
}
```

and I echo rendering content in the view.

```
echo $renderer->render($model);
```

but it render nothing. Please help me. thanks.
and also its fine work with zf1 by this two lines.

```
$this->userinfoAction();
$this->$render('userinfo');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you have done should work with following miner changes

```
public function userinforeceiveAction()
{   
    $renderer = new PhpRenderer();

    $map = new Resolver\TemplateMapResolver(array(
    // first mistake
    // __DIR__ is the directory of application controller, not the path of views 
    // second mistake
    // 'userinfo' should be '(controller)/(action)'
    'userinfo' => __DIR__ . '/userinfo.phtml',
        ));

        // third mistake
        // since $map is a resolver instance, this is wrong
        $resolver = new Resolver\TemplateMapResolver($map); // no need
        $renderer->setResolver($resolver);
        // should be $renderer->setResolver($map);
        $model = new ViewModel();
        // 'userinfo' should be changed
        $model->setTemplate('userinfo');

        // big mistake
        // what you are returning here is new instance of view model
        return new ViewModel();
        // instead you should return $model 
}
```

No need of this line within the view

```
echo $renderer->render($model);
```

But the best and recommended way is to inject through the module configuration file,
as [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025589/adam-lundrigan) said

The [documentation](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/zend.view.renderer.php-renderer.html) will provide better explanation

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the ZF2 MVC layer you don't need to instantiate your own view rendering, just return a ViewModel instance and it will take care of the rest:

```
public function userinforeceiveAction()
{
    $vm = new ViewModel();
    $vm->setTemplate('userinfo');
    return $vm;
}
```

For an example of how to use view models see Akrabat's ZF2TestApp: http://zf2test.akrabat.com/

The associated ZF2 code is linked at the bottom of that page and the template map is configured in the [module configuration file](https://github.com/akrabat/ZF2TestApp/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L78)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the [skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) on how to render stuff in a MVC environment.

Principally you're doing it the right way. But why are you creating a renderer and a resolver without using it? I guess to set a rendering strategy and the templates? That's nothing to be done in a controller but in your application's / module's configuration.

On the other hand, you don't echo the result of the renderer in your view - the renderer returns the result of your view(s) which is then echo'd by your application (you don't do this by yourself).

Comment: can u help something more. I didn't understand that much.

Comment: You should be a bit more specific in your questions then and read the documentation & run and try the skeleton application.